# sudo react-native run-android giving error

Tags: react-native

I have no idea what is the error when i want to run my react native app.

```
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

10 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 7 up-to-date
/var/www/html/react/LotteryApp/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/var/www/html/react/LotteryApp/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/var/www/html/react/LotteryApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
    at buildAndRun (/var/www/html/react/LotteryApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:137:41)
    at then.result (/var/www/html/react/LotteryApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

It was working fine yesterday. I can't understand on the above code. What kind of error is this ? Please help on this. I tied to find on google. But cant find anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you build the app with Android studio once?

If not, build it first in Android Studio and install it through Android Studio.

### To Build the app in android studio:

- Open Android Studio.
- Open **react_native_project**/android  with Android Studio.
- Wait for all it to build automatically, if some errors are present, try running Build > Clean Build.
- Gradle should build successfully.

Then try:`react-native run-android`.

If it still does not work, stop the process and then run `react-native start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: I have done it using react native. It is suddenly giving this error today.

Comment: This is probably happening  because of the new react-native release 2 days ago. Sometimes there will be an issue with the gradle versions. Just open android studio, build the app successfully and then you can run it using `react-native run-android` or `react-native start`.

Comment: I have already tried with react-native start. But i got the same error.

Comment: After building in Android Studio?

Comment: How can i build android studio ?

Comment: Install Android Studio, open the folder __react_native_pro__\android folder and make sure Android Studio doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: i am using my android phone directly